# Integrate bitcoins with MSE

Tags: discussion

There are some users who have put much effort into their answers, and sometimes I'd like to reward them. This would be an optional feature, of course.

Note that I don't want to discuss the technical implementation here, only what people think about the idea.

Comment: If you want to reward such users, you should give them bounty ;)

Comment: meta.SO: [Pay money to SO for quick support](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57850/pay-money-to-so-for-quick-support)

Comment: BTW I remember that there was a question offering real money as a bounty [at MathOverflow](http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1212/100-bounty-do-invariant-measures-maximize-the-integral/). I do not know whether something similar happened at MSE, too.

Comment: @Prism I don't have enough points to do that.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Would it be against the rules to put a bitcoin address in the personal info field?

Comment: @DanielR Done. Excellent idea, please post that as an answer.

Answer (score 25):

I wholly and entirely disagree.  This goes against the entire philosophy of the StackExchange network.

In addition, I'll copy a previous comment of [Michael Greinecker](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11377/should-we-charge-to-answer-obvious-homework-with-no-effort/11379#comment43076_11379) which seems mostly apropos:

> I don't mind too much being a user and moderator on a site that some people use to get their homework done. I wouldn't want to explain why I'm on a site that helps cheaters for money though.

Answer (score -14):

As mentioned in the comments, you can have your bitcoin address in your profile. If you want to be explicit, append the following to your posts:

[image]