# Is it possible to pay to get a quick answer?

Tags: support, answers

Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) section of the Stack Overflow site it seems that there are some payment services to have quick answers in any Stack Exchange community: is this true?

Comment: I think that's their paid-for product, not the network of Q&A sites.  As far as I know the only way of "paying" for a quick answer here is to offer a bounty

Comment: I am automatically suspicious of people wanting quick answers; I would be *much* more suspicious if they started offering money!

Comment: Somewhat related older post on this meta: [Integrate bitcoins with MSE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11629). (Maybe also some other [questions linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/11629) are worth having a look.) In the comments you can see a link to this declined feature request on [meta.se]: [Pay money to SO for quick support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57850).

Comment: Adding monetary aspects to this website is a surefire way to guarantee that I, and some other experts, will stop participating.

Comment: Though I am **nowhere** as prolific or as much of an expert as Asaf, I too would leave this site if answers were monetized.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I ask this question because I am looking for a teacher: I am self-taught. This does not mean that I am not grateful to all the users who  helped me this year ** without any reward **: in fact only thanks to their rigorous and wonderful explanations I was able to study Set Theory, Topology, Linear Algebra and now Differential Geometry  by learning so some (serious) math; in particular I am completely grateful to professors Scott and Brandsma who help me every day for free and for this I thank them with all my heart.

Comment: @AsafKaragila However I feel that I still have to improve a lot and unfortunately I believe that to do this a real (physical) teacher is needed, that's all.

Comment: Yes, you want to get a teacher. That's fine. Others don't care for that as much. The idea, as a whole, has terrible implications, even if *your* intentions are good.

Comment: @AsafKaragila  Okay, so do you believe that it is possible to learn math by autodidact?

Comment: I think that this would be a terrible thing to add to math.se. I also think that it would be nice if anyone who knew of a a web site where the O.P. could find what they're looking for would post it. Or even just a site where they could ask where to find such a teacher. "No" is a fine answer; "No, try asking at X" is better.

Comment: @Antonio: I don't see how that's related to my previous comment. History is rife with examples of autodidacts. It's never easy, of course.

Comment: @JonathanZ Your comment comes across as quite critical of the above comments. Yes, it would be better if we could direct them to what they want. However, there is no reason I can see why anyone here would know of such a place.

Comment: @user1729: It was totally not my intention to criticize other comments. As I am someone who leans strongly on the side that says that some things belong on this site and some things don't, I just wanted to point out that, while we are telling people that their idea doesn't belong here it'd be nice if we could tell them where it does. (I don't know of a place where the OP can find what they want either, but there are all sorts of people with all sorts of connections on math.se. Maybe someone does.)

Comment: If there is a university anywhere near you, Antonio, there is probably a graduate student there keen to make a little extra money by taking on some tutoring work. You could try contacting the department to see whether they could tell you how to contact such a student.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, this is not possible. You get quick answers by writing good questions and sharing your research/attempts. Bounties might work but you can only post them after 48 hours. All suggestions to implement 'payment for answers' have been heavily downvoted, e.g. [Would it better the community if we got compensated for posts? Even with minuscule alt coins?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229225/295232) As are any attempts to indicate urgency, e.g. [An "urgent" tag for questions that need answers within minutes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6506/295232).

What you linked to is a way for a company or team to privately share internal knowledge among employees or team members. You pay Stack Overflow to host the 'community', but it does not offer support to pay colleagues or something.

Comment: Okay, so what is that I read in the link I post?

Comment: I don't understand precisely what you wrote in the final part of the answer.

Comment: Do you want say that the service I indicate offers tutors payment support?